# How to write a Javascript function with ability to preserve values between calls

Tags: javascript, arrays

Actually I am drawing a graph wherein I am populating the first 30 or so points as soon as the chart loads and then I am giving a call to another function which will give a new random value with the additional property that if this number is greater then its immediate preceding number point in the graph or the number coming after wards then we add additional attribute to that number like different color.

Here is my code

```
              events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];

                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), //current time

                            color = 'red', // default color

                            y = getYData();// this function is supplying the values

                        //condifiton
                        if the condition is true do the follwoing

                         series.addPoint({
                            x: x,
                            y: y,
                            color: color// pass the color
                        }, true, true);

                       else 
                        series.addPoint({
                            x: x,
                            y: y
                                         // No color required
                        }, true, true);


                    }, 1000);

          function getYValue(){

           // Code for giving the yValue. How to write this?

          }
```

But in this I need to be able to preserve the value in between calls.

Is this possible in Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Capture it using a variable in a higher scope than the _function_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `y` variable in outer scope so it will preserve its value between interval calls:

```
{
  var series = this.series[0];
  var y = 0;

  setInterval(function () {

    var newy = getYData();
    // do smething here
    // in y - old value, in newy  - new one
    y = newy;
    ...

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following;

```
var foo = (function () { // an IIFE creates a scope
    var x = 0; // which we can use to form a closure over a variable
    return function foo() { // and define a function within this scope too
        return ++x; // which uses the variable
    };
}());
foo(); // 1
foo(); // 2
foo(); // 3
```

Comment: FWIW, the IIFE creates a new scope, not necessarily a closure.

Comment: What is FWIW and IIFE?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, knowing which words to use to explain exactly what I mean can be confusing. How's the wording now?

Comment: @user1590011 _FWIW_ stands for _for what it's worth_. _IIFE_ stands for _immediately invoked function expression_ and means a _function_ which is written as an _expression_ and gets _invoked_ immediately after it has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object or class of some sort. Any sort. That's what objects *do*.

Comment: Please be more elaborate. I am not very much at ease with javascript

Comment: @user1590011 you're in the wrong place then. Try a textbook or various sites you can learn javascript from.

Comment: Sure but I also need to solve this thing at hand first.

Comment: @user1590011 that's your problem. Somewhere else please. voting to close this question now.